# Google Maps JS API 3 - Editable Forms in Custom Overlay

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API to provide a form in a custom Map Overlay, similar to a native InfoWindow. I used [an example by google](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html) to create a custom overlay, using their [`OverlayView`](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#OverlayView) Prototype.

Eventually this overlay doesn't have the same behaviour [`InfoWindow`](http://code.google.com/intl/en-En/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow) has regarding editing. Interacting with the window results in interaction with the map. One can neither select text in the window nor edit an input-field. Events are delegated to the map.

I already tried to play around with z-index, which won't work.

In [their example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html) you can't select text either - therefore you might have a look at [their source](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html).

Comment: Anyone you don't just use an InfoWindow. This is a square peg round hole situation.

Comment: I need to style the InfoBox very individually - therefore I can't use an `InfoWindow`

Comment: What styling do you need? It's possible that problem may be easier to solve.

Comment: @Trott: I am using a complete individual box that basically only needs one `div` - all the rest is css. Therefore I need to disable all the other styles an `InfoWindow` has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually is a question of event propagation. Google provides another less obvious example which solves the problem:

> http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/src/infobox.js

---> **UPDATE 01/2015**

[Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201665/ian-mackinnon) added [another example that blocks propagation of all map events](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js?r=198) in comments.

Comment: There's [another example that blocks propagation of all map events](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js?r=198). Search for 'addEvents_' in the source.

Comment: So to summarize, just manually disable all propagation. I never dreamed that'd be the best way to deal with this. I think it's sad there's not just a 'disablePropagation' setting. IMHO @IanMackinnon's example link is simpler to read and more comprehensive.